# How to add underline separator between rows when printing Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

please see below a dataframe example. What I need is to put a line separating first three rows from others with an underline when printing the dataframe. I tried to use indexes to print first 3 rows, then print underline as a string, and then print the rest of rows but since every time the column names are printed also, this is not what I need. The output needed is on the attached image and below. It might be simple but I tried to find the answer and no result for now. Appreciate your help!

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {"Racer Name": ["Brian", "Oscar", "Michael", "John"], "Team Name": ["Ferrari", "Honda", "Toyota", "BMW"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict, index=list(range(0, 4)))
print(df)
```

[image: output_needed]

Comment: Where do you want to print the dataframe? Do you want to print it to a console?  Or do you use a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Yes, it's going to be printed to a console. That's why I thought styling is not the way I need to go here also. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the DataFrame to a string then you can insert a line like this.

```
s = df.to_string().replace('\n3', '\n'+'_'*23+'\n3')
print(s)
```

**Output**

[image: df with line]

Comment: Thank you! You answered my question and looks like the problem is solved!

Comment: I marked your answer as useful but looks like due to this is my first question and no reputation here, it's recorded but not publicly displayed. Thanks again!